# How to autocompile a picklist?

Tags: formula, picklist, custom-field, administration

I would like to know if it's possible to autocompile a picklist field with a value of different picklist on others object.

In this case, I created a picklist with a name: Campo Prova

**Picklist example**

[image]

In this part, I have a picklist with a name: Campo Prova 2

**Second Picklist**

[image]

Now I want to copy the values of "Campo prova" inside the second picklist "Campo Prova 2". It's possible on Salesforce? maybe with a formula?

Best regards,

E.P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your picklist is Restricted (only allows values in the given set), you can promote it to a Global Value Set by clicking Edit for the field, then Promote to Global Value Set.

[image]

Then, you can use the Global Value Set for any and all picklists that need to share their values.